# Correlate IPs in list with subnetwork list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list filled with "next hop" ip addresses which is about 12.000 long (mylist). What I am trying to do is to find the outbound interface based on an other list which contains the outbound interface and the related sub-network. This list contains about 3.000 items. So basically, I want to match the IPs with the sub-networks so as to get the outbound interfaces eg 172.17.32.2 belongs to '172.17.235.2/255.255.255.252' so 'GigabitEthernet1/0/0' should be associated with 172.17.32.2. The prefixes are not fixed,. The following works but it is too ugly and slow since 12*3*10^6 'if' statements are performed.:

```
for i,ip in enumerate(mylist):
    for j,member in enumerate(outbound):
        if ipaddress.ip_address(ip) in ipaddress.ip_network(member[0],strict=False):
           tmp.insert(0,ip)
           #member[1] contains the interfaces, member[0] the subnetworks
           tmp.insert(1,member[1]) 
           result.append(tmp)
           tmp=[]
```

Can you experts please make this faster/more effective?Thx in advance.

Comment: Not an easy thing to optimize. Also optimization is not the core topic of SO. As a personal suggestion, you should consider using PostgreSQL. It can handle this kind of queries on IPs / networks very well.

Comment: I will give it a try.